# Yii model validation

Tags: php, validation, yii

Hey can anyone help me with validating a model in yii?

```
class MyFormModel extends FormModel
{
        public myAttribute1;
        public myAttribute2;

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->myAttribute1 = 'blablabla'
                $this->user = new User();
        }

        public function rules()
        {
                $rules = parent::rules()
                $rules[] = array('myAttribute1', 'required', 'message' => 'this is required');
                $rules[] = array(#i need to add validation for $user->firstname here#);
                return $rules;
        }

}
```

how do i validate an attribute from another model?

Comment: What kind of validation you require?

Comment: i need the same 'required' on the firstname...

Comment: i tried $rules[] = array('user.firstname', 'required', 'message' => 'this is required'); but is not working

Comment: add the attribute to this Model like `public MyOtherAttribute;` then in rules add it like: `$rules[] = array('myAttribute1, MyOtherAttribute', 'required', 'message' => 'this is required');`. This will validate that attribute in the same Model. With this you bring the attribute from other model to this model to be validated and then you can pass this value to the other Model and save the other model. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: i know what you mean, but the problem is that if i use many models and each model have about 5 attribures, then my formmowal will have too many attributes, and that is the reason i am doing like this. i need individual validation for each attribute

Comment: Then you have to define the rules for every attribute in it own model and initialize all the models you need then upon saving the main model just validate the other models as well like : `$model->validate(); $model2->validate(); model3->validate();` but with this you will have to check if validation is false then raise and error using `$model->addError('MyAttribute','This is required field.');`

Answer (score 0):

You can write the rules for the firstname attribute in user model itself. And on this page you can validate this particular field by using

```
$userMDl = new User();
if($userMDl->validate(array('firstname ')) 
     // valid
}
```

Comment: i did came across this way, but lets say that in a particular place i need validation on firstname to be in a format and another place i need it in another format, how do i do this?? i would prefer if i could do in in my formmodel itself :/

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your `MyFormModel` attribute

```
private $firstname;
```

override `init` method

```
public function init(){
    ...
    $this->firstname = $user->firstname;
}
```

and in your `rules`

```
$rules[] = array('firstname', 'required', 'message' => 'firstname is required');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own validation function in form class. Please see next article: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/